# How do I edit and delete entityform submissions?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using entityform for a particular submission. I set the rule When submitting the entityform, which is stored in a particular content type. It works well, but when I edit and delete the particular entityform submissions it doesn't work.

Is there any rule or hook available to store entityform submissions to a particular content type?

Answer (score 0):

use entityform hook_form_alter with devel module in this case i suggest to view your data before submit button ... and entityform hook_form_insert to view your data after submission button using devel module or drupal_set_message. You can actually alter in hook_form_alter button to  store entityform submission to particular content type.